# python3 struct pack returns incorrect value

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct

```py
import struct

>>> p = struct.pack("@2I", 7, 10)
>>> p
b'\x07\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00'
```

When I pack the value 10, it returns incorrect value

```py
>>> p = struct.pack("@I", 10)
>>> p
b'\n\x00\x00\x00'
```

why is it printing out as binary \n,0,0,0

Comment: `int.from_bytes(b'\n\x00\x00\x00', 'little')` = `10`

Answer (score 0):

this is correct.  `I` indicates the value has to be packed with 4 bytes and has to be interpreted as `unsigned int`. So you see 4 byte value in the output.

If you are wondering why you get `\n`:

`struct.pack` returns you a `bytes` object, and when you print `bytes` object, it represents all bytes that can be printed as ASCII and other values are printed as hex and denoted with `\x` prefix...

decimal 10 is represented in ASCII as `\n`.

use `hex()` method in bytes object to see the non translated hex data.

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack("@I", 10).hex()  # or use .hex(':') to separate bytes while printing
'0a000000'
```

You can double check this by feeding the output of `struct.pack` to `int.from_bytes`

```
>>> int.from_bytes(struct.pack("@I", 10), 'little')
10
```